# SWIFT: Draw UILabel under UIImage

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to iOS development, and I'm building a custom UIFlowLayout, I'm currently in the process of building my custom cell object which consist of an image and label.

I want to draw the label under the UIImage, but I don't know how to anchor it directly under the UIImage.

The layout I want to achieve is something like:

```
===========================
[      Navigation Bar     ]
===========================

 [  Image  ]   [  Image  ]
 [  Label  ]   [  Label  ]

 [  Image  ]   [  Image  ]
 [  Label  ]   [  Label  ]

 [  Image  ]   [  Image  ]
 [  Label  ]   [  Label  ]

===========================
[         Tab Bar         ]
===========================
```

The code I'm currently using for my `UICollectionViewCell` subclass looks like:

```
var label     : UILabel!
var imageView : UIImageView!

override init(frame: CGRect)
{
    // Initialize the frame object
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()

    // Set up the image
    imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.size.width, height: frame.size.height))
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    contentView.addSubview(imageView)

    // Make the rectangle a circle by adjusting the corner radius, relative to 50% of the bounds
    self.layer.cornerRadius = (frame.size.width / 100) * 50

    // Set up the label (how do I do the anchoring?)
    label = UILabel(frame: frame)
    label.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(UIFont.smallSystemFontSize())
    label.textAlignment = .Center
    label.text = "Alexander Sims"
    contentView.addSubview(label)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting the label's frame, you could use the imageView.frame as reference.

Something like this:

```
 let labelX = imageView.frame.origin.x
 let labelY = imageView.frame.origin.y + imageView.frame.height

 label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(labelX, labelY, imageView.frame.width, 21)) // The last variable, 21, is the label's height.  Change as you see fit.
```

Comment: Thanks Ron, that solved it...very new to iOS dev so feeling a bit lost :)